# How can I copy an Array to another minus user specified Elements AND write and replace the new list the a .txt file

Tags: c#, arrays

Here is what I have so far, obviously you can subtract arrays the way i did. And I also need to know how to write the new list to a .txt file that i already have ("records.txt")

```
public static int deleteRecord(string num)
{
        int amount;
        int.TryParse(num, out amount);
        string[] arrayRecords = File.ReadAllLines("Records.txt").ToArray();

        string[] newArrayRecords = arrayRecords - arrayRecords[amount];

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newArrayRecords[amount]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(amount);
        return amount;
}
```

Comment: what is amount ? is that your index or you want to delete the line that contains your amount?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to delete a particular value from a file and that is why you have chosen the "num" parameter to be a string.

If so then this will work:

```
public static void deleteRecord(string num)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Records.txt").ToList();

    if (lines.Remove(num) == true)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines("Records.txt", lines.ToArray<string>());
    }
}
```

There are a couple of things to point out in your code. Firstly in your example, if you couldn't convert num to an int then you would be trying to remove the value of 0 from your file - which you may not want.

Secondly File.ReadAllLines already returns an Array of strings, so you don't need the .ToArray() at the end. In fact that converts the string[] array to an object[] array - which is not what you want.

I've converted it to a List as they are easier to work with. I only save the file if the item has been removed.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you want to remove the line that contains specified amount, if so you can try this:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("Records.txt")
           .Where(x => !x.Contains(amount.ToString());

// this will replace all prev. lines with the new ones
File.WriteAllLines("Records.txt", lines);
```

If you want to remove all lines that comes before this line then you can try:

```
var allLines = File.ReadLines("Records.txt");
var line = allLines.Where(x => x.Contains(amount.ToString()).First();
var lineIndex = allLines.IndexOf(line);
File.WriteAllLines("Records.txt",lines.GetRange(lineIndex, allLines.Count - lineIndex));
```

Ofcourse that answer assumes that there is line that contains amount.If there isn't then second code snippet could possibly throw exception.

Comment: To skip all the lines before the one that contains the amount: `var linesAfter = allLines.SkipWhile(x => !x.Contains(amount.ToString()))`. Then you can call `File.WriteAllLines(linesAfter);` Add another `Skip(1)` if you want to skip the containing line, too.